# What is different in case-insensitivity between HashSet Contains and set operations such as Except?

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain the following behavior:

```
var h1 = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "apple" };
Console.WriteLine(h1.Contains("APPLE")); // Expected - returns True.

var h2 = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "APPLE" };
Console.WriteLine(h1.Except(h2).Count() == 0); // Surprisingly returns False!
```

I can pass a case-insensitive comparer to Except() to allow a case-insensitive set operation, but I wonder why I need to? - since my h1 HashSet is constructed with a case-insensitive comparer.

Comment: `Contains` is [`HashSet<T>.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1), a method from HashSet, so it uses it's comparer. On the other hand `Except` is [`Enumerable.Except<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1), a Enumerable method, so it uses the default comparer of the `T` type.

Comment: Because `Except` method from `System.Linq` (unlike `Contains` from `HashSet<T>`) and you should pass comparer to its [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) `h1.Except(h2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count() == 0` returns `true`

Comment: Both answers above explain it. If one of you pastes into an Answer, I will set it as Accepted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1) method belongs to `HashSet<T>` class, but [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1) method is extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` and part of `System.Linq`. To get an expected behavior you have to use a [proper overload of `Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__), which accepts a comparer. Then the following code prints an expected `true` value

```cs
var h2 = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "APPLE" };
Console.WriteLine(h1.Except(h2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count() == 0);
```